# How to redirect non supported Deep-link URL to Browser

Tags: android, deep-linking

My app supports deep-linking from email and external links. The app opens and navigates to specific screen based on the url. But i don't support all the url path

Example, For `http://my-deeplink-url/page1` app should open and for
`http://my-deeplink-url/page2` should open on browser.

Since the app support the `my-deeplink-url` uri path, for both the link app opens.
Its ok, if the app opens, but needs to redirect to the browser if the url not supported.

I tried starting the activity using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` , but this again opens the app , as it supports the same deep-link url.

What is the explicit intent to open the url in browser.

Comment: where is the code.

Comment: is there any pattern in your deep link url those which  has supported deep link and those which does not

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by investigating the `pathPrefix` options: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html